# In the database, what is the relationship between the customer_entity table and sales?

Tags: customer, sales, database

I'm trying to merge Magento orders between two different stores and I'm tracking down all of the relationships. The one I'm currently trying to figure out is the customer_entity table and the sales_* tables. I don't see a foreign key or entity_id that would line the two up.

How does Magento associate customer tables with sales?

Comment: See `sales_flat_order.customer_id` Since customer can check out as guest, then customer_id is either null for quest or contain the customer id for register member

Comment: Thanks! That's the one. You should post it as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `sales_flat_order.customer_id`

Since customer can check out as guest, then customer_id is either null for quest or contain the customer id for register member